# Line behind transparent text

Tags: html, css, text

This piece of layout shows what I want to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzTnV.png

Basically, I need to make :
----- Text ----------------- Text again --------

Of course, the lines need to be sized automatically, because the text will be a different width on each page. I tried a few things, but still nothing...
Please notice that the text can't have a background, it needs to be transparent.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/979/

Closest one was this, but the line is still going through text, and it can't be!

Example:

> Untitled Document
>       
>           #content {
>               width: 1000px;
>               height: 100px;
>               background: red;
>           }
>
> ```
>     #left_column {
>         width: 680px;
>         float: left;
>         margin-left: 15px;
>         background: green;
>     }
>
>     #right_column {
>         width: 290px;
>         float: left;
>     }
>
>     .line1 {
>         width: 10%;
>         height: 3px;
>         background: yellow;
>         float: left;
>         min-width: 20px;
>         margin-top: 40px;
>     }
>     .line2 {
>         width: 75%;
>         max-width: 71%;
>         height: 3px;
>         background: yellow;
>         float: left;
>         min-width: 20px;
>         margin-top: 40px;
>     }
>
>     h1 {
>         float: left;
>         font-size: 48px;
>         margin: 10px 15px 0px 15px;
>     }
>
> body {
>         background: blue;
>         color: white;
>     }
> </style> </head> <body>
> <div id="content">
>     <div id="left_column">
>         <div class="line1"></div>
>         <h1>Title</h1>
>         <div class="line2"></div>
>     </div>
>     <div id="right_column"> <h1>Title again</h1> <div class="line1"></div>    </div>      </div> </body> </html>
> ```

Here I set the line width on percentages, but when the text is longer, the line falls to the second row, and I only want to it make smaller.

I hope you guys know what I mean..
Greets!

Comment: Is your actual background an image or a solid colour? I assume an image or this would not be an issue but wanted to confirm

Comment: my background is something like background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5). To not be missunderstood, not the background of "content div" is problem, but that line.

Comment: Okay, how about two HR(s) with absolute positioning? Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/980 Thenceforth, you can specify media queries to make it responsive.

Comment: If the background is a colour, then you can set the same colour for the text background and use your border idea or other ideas hiding the line behind text. This obviously will not work if your background is an image

Comment: @Nix thank you for respond, but look what i made with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/981/. I want to achieve to line get automatically resized with text.

Comment: @Huangism thank you for respond too! But what if my BG need to be a semi-transparent like 0,5 opacity.

Comment: @Huls nevermind, my method only works if the background is solid colour. I see the issue with translucent background now

Comment: You mean to say that dynamic text will be displayed there?

Comment: Okay, set font-size in em(s), make hr and h2 blocks fluid - http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/985

Comment: As I mentioned before, you'll need to set media queries to handle this on smaller screens.

Comment: This project won't be responsive, i only need to write lines which will handle resiing when there will be "text tex text" instead of "text"

Answer (score 2):

if it's a solid color background you could add a class to the `<h2>`

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="bluecolor"><span>THIS IS A TEST</span></h2>
<p>this is some content</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.bluecolor span {background:blue;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jGHS/983/